# Getting zipcode into a textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, location

So I looked at the sample code by Apple for getting the users location. This works fine for me and the location its display is correct.

Now I want to display the zipcode in a textfield called "zipCode" that I have created. How would I do that?

tryed:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"lat%f - lon%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
    zipCode.text = self.placemark.postalCode;
}
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: no i didnt. But i also dont know how i can display it in a nslog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use reverseGeocodeLocation, like:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation *location = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
         if ([placemarks count] > 0)
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             zipCode.text = placemark.postalCode;
         }
     }];
}
```

Remember to import the CoreLocation.framework

Comment: i get 3 errors:

/Users/florianschaal/Developer/Janssenpakketapp/Janssenpakketapp/NewTrackTraceViewController.m:83:24: Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

/Users/florianschaal/Developer/Janssenpakketapp/Janssenpakketapp/NewTrackTraceViewController.m:84:1: Expected identifier or '('

/Users/florianschaal/Developer/Janssenpakketapp/Janssenpakketapp/NewTrackTraceViewController.m:84:34: Use of undeclared identifier 'location'

Comment: You deleted your previous code: CLLocation *location = [locations objectAtIndex:0]; I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Reverse Geocoding if you want covert informations about a location on the map.
It's all written [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW1).